# accessing multiple fields in django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a django form with following fields:

```
<form method="POST" style="display: none" name="form-mdm" action="find_files_and_password" id="form-mdm" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal form-margin" >
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="id_certificate_mdm"></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type = "hidden" name ="serviceid" value="2"/>
                <input type="file" name="f1" id="id_1"  required>
                <input type="file" name="f2" id="id_2" required>
                <input  type="file" name="f3" id="id_3" required>
                <input  type="text" name="sometext" value="Enter text" id="id_text" required>
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

when i click on submit my POST action(a function say views.find_files_and_password should list my files like-
    file1=f1
    file2=f2
    file3=f3
    textval=sometext.
    Could anyone please suggest how can i do it inside my views.find_files_and_password function?(Dont consider the syntax error in the above code if any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you are asking here.

In your Django code, your files will be available inside `request.FILES`, which is a dictionary keyed by the input's `name` attribute, so f1, f2, f3.

Comment: Hi Daniel,ok... i got the half information. but how to address text field? it is not a file to use request.FILES

Comment: Come on, this is basic stuff which is in the documentation. `request.POST`.